# create multiple xml file from one xml file

Tags: xml, xslt

i have this xml file

```
<DataArea>
<TB001I>
<IOCOD>aaa</IOCOD>
<IODESC>desc</IODESC>
</TB001I>
<TB001I>
<IOCOD>bbb</IOCOD>
<IODESC>desc</IODESC>
</TB001I>
<TB001I>
<IOCOD>ccc</IOCOD>
<IODESC>desc</IODESC>
</TB001I>
</DataArea>
```

i would create 3 xml file each one like

```
<DataArea>
<TB001I>
<IOCOD>aaa</IOCOD>
<IODESC>desc</IODESC>
</TB001I>
</DataArea>

<DataArea>
<TB001I>
<IOCOD>bbb</IOCOD>
<IODESC>desc</IODESC>
</TB001I>
</DataArea>

<DataArea>
<TB001I>
<IOCOD>ccc</IOCOD>
<IODESC>desc</IODESC>
</TB001I>
</DataArea>
```

i'm new with XSLT
i don't know how to iterate with xslt to extract each node and create a new xml file
can you help me on that?
thank you

Comment: What version of XSLT, and if 1.0 which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: it is XSLT 1.0, what do you mean for which xslt processor

Comment: There's no standard way to send output to more than one destination in XSLT 1.0, so you need to use a processor-specific extension mechanism to achieve it.  What tool or library are you using to execute the transformation?

Comment: See here how to find out which XSLT processor you are using: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244370/how-can-we-check-that-which-xslt-processor-uses-as-default-in-solr/25245033#25245033